# How to split a char?

Tags: c

working on an assignment for university and I need to use strtok to get users input for a grid, for example b1 - d4 would move a piece from b1 to d4. I'm currently using strtok to split b1 - d4 into a startingPosition of b1 and an ending position of d4. Now I want to split this b1 into "b" and "1" so I can convert b to an integer of 1 (because it starts with 0) and 1 to an 
integer of 0.
This is my code for this bit so far:

```
 {
char input[20];
char *start, *end;
int n = 0;

fgets(input, 20, stdin);
/* clear new line */
input[strlen(input)-1]='\0';
/* Extract first string */
if(strlen(input)==0) return 0;

start=strtok(input, DELIMS);
printf("%s\n", start);
n++;
while( n < 2){
end=strtok(NULL, DELIMS);
if (end == NULL) break; else n++;
printf("%s\n\n", end);
}

}
```

So basically it's getting the input and storing it in start and end, so in the case of moving b1 - d4 i'll have *start = b1 *end = d4. The part i'm struggling with is now splitting the char *start into two chars, or a char array of "b" and "1". Am I going about this all wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than looking at the answers, do a little research on pointer and array equivalence in C, and hopefully you'll understand what you need to do. As it is, your question shows no research effort at all.

Answer (score 1):

If your token will always have the same length just

```
char b;
int  x;

b = token[0] - 'a';
x = (int)(token[1] - '0') - 1;
```

suppose that `token` points to the string `"b1"`, then `b` will have the value of the character `b` and `x` will be the integer `1`. You must check that the token is splittable, i.e. that it has 2 characters.

Strings in c are nothing but a sequence of bytes terminated by a special character `'\0'`, so for example `strlen()` counts how many bytes where there before the `'\0'` is encountered.

Since token is a pointer to the memory where these bytes are stored, using the array subscript operator dereferences the pointer after advancing it by the index value i.e. `token[0] == *token;` and `token[1] == *(token + 1);` I hope this clarifies.

If you want to convert `b` to an integer, you should take care of upper case too, so you might want to do something like

```
int b_integer;

if (b >= 'a')
    b_integer = b - 'A';
else
    b_integer = b - 'a';
```

**Recomendation**:

Don't deliberately use the `strlen()` function to compute the length of a string, the length is not stored anywhere and `strlen()` calculates it on every call, so you should actually store the returned value and use that.

Also, you never check if the first call to `strtok()` returned a non-`NULL` value.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I didn't realise that it was being stored in a manner that was accessible by using [0] and [1]. I had believed it was a char of "b1" rather than an array of [b] and [1] thanks!

Comment: Question asks b should be converted to integer where are you converting it to integer you are just keeping itvas char

Comment: Sorry, the conversion is 1=0, 2=1, 3=2 etc - a=0,b=1,c=2 etc.

Comment: @Ryan are they always lowercase letters? Is it a chess board?

Comment: They're not always lowercase letters(depends on what the user enters), it is not a chess board, but it's similar.

Comment: @Ryan And do upper case letters have the same meaning than lowercase letters? BTW, did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Yes they do, but I was more just looking how to do the initial spliting of the string, I can work the rest out by myself. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: I thought so, that's why I didn't mention that in my answer. Im glad to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your *vaild* token will have a format of `<single_letter><one_digit_number>`, you can use *index* to get the value.

For example,

```
start=strtok(input, DELIMS);
```

Now, if start contains `A1`,

- `start[0]` is `A`
- `start[1]` is `1` [ASCII]

If you want to get the corresponding `int` value of the ASCII stored in `start[1]`, you can simply use `int move = (start[1] - '0')` which will give you the `int` value *as* an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

For your question:

> so I can convert b to an integer of 1 (because it starts with 0) and 1
>   to an integer of 0

Check the code below:

```
char *p = "b1";
int a,b;

a = (int) (p[0] - 97);
b = (int) (p[1] - '0');
```